# Is remmina an startup application in 16.04

Tags: 16.04

I found out after 2 week of installing ubuntu that I had remmina running at startup on Ubuntu 16.04.
I did not set remina as startup app.
Is that normal/default behaviour?/

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither Remmina, nor the Slack desktop, nor the System load indicator are startup applications by default. As far as I know, the Slack desktop is not even *installed* by default.

Comment: I'm curious, though, as to how these applications would have been set as startup applications without the user's knowledge. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe they set themselves as startup applications when first run? Remmina does it for certain.