# gnome-shell has high CPU usage after 18.04 upgrade

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell

Upgraded from 17.10 to 18.04. The gnome shell constantly spikes to >200% cpu usage and is especially bad when heavy interaction with the Xorg window manager occurs (web browsers, vlc media player, etc.). GPU is fine at <2% (GTX 1070 with Nvidia 390 drivers).

Restarting gnome-shell temporarily fixes the issue, but it resumes sporadic behavior after several minutes. When this occurs, the system is barely usable as frame rate dips to <5 fps.

Also tried updating BIOS. No effect.

Any ideas for a solution for restoring system stability?

Comment: Facing the same issue, yet the accepted answer did not solve it, unfortunately. Any other ideas? Is it maybe because I have nvidia AND Intel HD graphics?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have updated from 17.10 as well, and I started getting those crazy 5 fps interface lags and high CPU usage by gnome-shell - it helped me to run `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`, which fetched and updated nvidia drivers

Comment: That worked like a charm! It appears that for whatever reason the gpu was not being utilized by `gnome-shell` as now gnome stays <=25% cpu and gpu is at a nice 5% avg utilization. Additionally, running `nvidia-smi` shows that `gnome-shell` is actually utilizing the gpu as opposed to before when it just showed Xorg.

Any thoughts on why this fixed it? I already had the 390 drivers installed before (directly from Nvidia's website).

Comment: Yeah, same situation - had 390 drivers installed before (on 17.10), but they didn't work properly with gnome-shell before this command. Don't know why