# one cpu core is always 100 ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, cpu

I'm using ubuntu 18.04 as my os but something is troubling me. One of cpu cores is always near 100 and it makes my fan loud although there is nothing heavily running on my system. Can anybody help me with this? [image: my cpu history]
[image: and here is my running processes]

Comment: Why don't you find which process is loading your CPU?

Comment: @Pilot6 I had checked it out but I did not find any thing special

Comment: Click the processes tab, selecat all processes and sort by CPu load. It will show you all.

Comment: @Pilot6        i added my processes list, you can check it

Comment: I am facing the same issue! This also seems to make my laptop super laggy! 
For me it seems to be somehow related to NVIDIA driver and or gdm3. Tried everything in here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033368/gnome-lags-so-bad-on-ubuntu-18-04 with only temporary success. Please help dear Internet!